# Return empty Vector collection instead of null

Tags: java, vector, collections

I have a function that returns a Vector and in case of an error, I want to return an empty Vector which can be checked using Collections.isEmpty by the calling method. But I am unable to find the way to do it as Collections provides Collections.emptyList functions for List, Maps, etc. but not for Vector and I am forced to return null by function which I want to avoid.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `return new Vector();` ?

Comment: or if you have an object, return vector.clear();

Comment: Will CollectionUtils.isEmpty support that?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to return a `Vector`. It's probably better for the return type to be an arbitrary`List` type instead. With that change, `Collections.emptyList()` is perfect. Otherwise, `new Vector()` is fine.

Comment: `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(null)` also returns true, so either way it wouldn't matter.

Comment: My function calls another service which returns a Vector, and wrapping a List around a vector seems unnecessary. 
new Vector() seems the right thing.

Comment: JavaDoc for Vector()   
  * Constructs an empty vector so that its internal data array
     * has size {@code 10} and its standard capacity increment is
     * zero.

Comment: Nobody said that you should wrap the `Vector`. A `Vector` *is* a `List`. So when your code receives a `Vector`, you can still process it as a `List`, which allows you to substitute `null` with `Collections.emptyList()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a `new Vector<X>()`, but a better solution would be to move away from `Vector` which has been obsolete for (many) years. Unless you require concurrency features, you can use an `ArrayList` instead.

You added that you receive the `Vector` from a third party service. Don't forget that a `Vector` is a `List`, so you could maybe use something like this:

```
public List<X> getData() {
  try {
    Vector<X> v = getDataFromService();
    return v;
  } catch (ServiceException e) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am dependent on Vector as I make calls to a legacy service which returns Vector only.

new Vector() seems right.

Comment: @adimoh the fact that the service **returns** a `Vector` does not prevent you from using `List`. It would be different, if the service demanded a `Vector` is input.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return an empty Vector which can be checked using
>   Collections.isEmpty

Do you want to return an empty Vector or do you want Collections.isEmpty() to return true when passed an empty Vector?
Generally, returning an empty Vector would indicate no error but an empty result - you should consider throwing a (checked) exception on an error - that will make the contract between the method and its caller clearer. If, at some later date, you want the method to be able to return an empty Vector to indicate an empty result (and no error) you will be able to without changing all the calling code.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use its own method?

```
 return vector.isEmpty() ? new Vector<?>() : vector;
```