# Replacing vector with arraylist

Tags: java

I am working on a legacy codebase which has references to `java.util.Vector` all over the place. I get sonar errors telling me to replace it with an `ArrayList`. Because of how ubiquitous the reference is, I want to take all precautions necessary to avoid any problems that could arise by replacing Vector with ArrayList.

I couldn't find anything about this (Possibly because it is so old an issue and most people must have moved past this atleast a decade ago). What are the things I should be looking out for ? Since vector is thread safe, what is a simpler way to replace this without causing threading issues if any ?

FYI this is a web project and doesn't make explicit use of multithreading.

Comment: Someone just posted something somewhat related here with an answer that touches ArrayList https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220769/return-empty-vector-collection-instead-of-null

Comment: Well, the JavaDoc on `Vector` states: "If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector." - If you are unsure whether a thread-safe implementation is needed or not I'd stick with Vector and tell Sonar to accept that.

Answer (score 0):

`Vector` is synchronized and doesn't accept `null` values. You could use

```
List<String> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>())
```

but it's not a 100% identical replacement. If you don't have good tests in your project don't replace `Vector` and add [`//NOSNAR`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/faq/) to disable Sonar check in given line.

Comment: There are 422 references to Vector. I have thought about adding `///NOSONAR` already. Adding `//NOSONAR` is not only tedious, it adds code smell with `//NOSONAR` strewn all over the place. Looking for a better solution.